# How to combine highpass and lowpass filter to implement a bandpass filter

Tags: filters, python, bandpass

I want to implement a bandpass filter by using and combining my highpass and lowpass filter functions in Python:

```
def lowpass(L,f):
 N = np.arange(0,L)-(L-1)/2 
 C = np.sinc(f*L)                              
 C *= signal.hamming(L)                         
 C /= np.sum(C)             
 return C

def highpass(L,f):
 Clp = ideal_lowpass(L,f)                                 
 Chp = np.zeros(L)     
 if L%2:                  
   Chp[int((L-1)/2)]=1      
 else:                      
   Chp[int((L-1)/2)]=0.5  
   Chp[int((L-1)/2+1)]=0.5
 Chp = Chp - Clp                                
 return Chp
```

I know there are easier ways to implement a bandpass filter, for example by using pythons firwin function:

```
B = signal.firwin(num, [f1, f2], pass_zero=False)
```

But is there any way you can combine the two highpass and lowpass filters to implement a bandpass filter without using the already built in python function? Any guidance would be helpful!

Comment: I wish we [had code highlighting](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/can-we-get-code-highlighting-turned-on-please)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cascade the high pass and the low pass by convolving the two impulse responses. This will result in a band pass of order $L_{BP} = L_{LP} + L_{HP} -1$

It's not the most efficient way of designing a band pass, but it will work.

Comment: As long as the cutoff for the low pass filter is lower than the cutoff for the high pass filter, but hopefully that's obvious to the OP.

Comment: You still can cascade them, but you just won't get to 0 dB anywhere.

Comment: And it won't work if you want a really narrow bandpass filter.  I.e., the z-domain equivalent of $\frac{s^2 + \omega_0^2}{s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_0 s + \omega_0^2}$ is right out.